# Word for "a change of altitude"

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a word that describes a generic change in altitude, something that could refer to both ascent or descent.

Comment: "altitude change"

Comment: Can you provide more context? An example sentence?

Comment: How about "ambiscent"?

Comment: Context would help, but "yaw" can be a verb as well as a noun, and could fit. If you're not sure your audience will understand "yaw," you could try "vertical movement/motion". (Yaw refers to movement outside the primary axis of movement, so means vertical movement for an airplane, but not for everything.)

Comment: Ambiscent seems to be the closest so far. @frances Unfortunately there really isn't any actual context, I was trying to find a word to describe games like TowerClimb and Spelunky where the primary goal is a change in altitude without relying on "platformer"

Comment: I tried a few dictionaries, and didn't find "ambiscent," but sometimes you just need to establish a new word if it doesn't exist already. And maybe this one does exist and I just didn't find it.

Comment: @frances My dictionary says that "yaw" is "twist or oscillate about a vertical axis". Pilots use it when they're turning, not changing altitude. Changing the horizontal angle is "pitch".

Comment: I suspect there aren't enough contexts where ascent and descent need to be referred to collectively that it warrants a single word. Just say "going up and down" or "climbing and descending".

Comment: Six words are used to regularly describe the rotational and linear movement of a vessel in each of three axes.

When a ship turns in its course, it *yaws*. When it rocks from side-to-side, it *rolls*. It *pitches* over waves.

When it is caught in a current it *surges* forward. It *sways* to the quayside when it is pulled with ropes and *heaves* into the water as it is charged with cargo and ballast.

Where relevant, these terms have been carried over from maritime usage to other domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need a single, attested word, maybe consider *climbing* ?

Though unadorned *climbing* is usually an ascent, mountaineers *climb up* and *climb down* mountains.

**Advantages**: short, natural, well-attested, easily-understood word. Useful in non-technical contexts, particularly if room for elaboration or qualification is available.

**Disadvantages**: implicit bias to ascent without qualification: a weakness in a technical context. Would be misunderstood in aeronautics.